# how to run cfloop on struct results in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I am new bie on coldfusion, Please help me to get All ID, Name, Type Using CFLOOP?

[image]

```
<cfset categoryList = application.salesforce.queryObject("SELECT Id, Name FROM Category__c") />
<cfdump var="#categoryList#"> 
<cfloop list="#structKeyList(categoryList)#" index="key"> 
<cfdump var="#categoryList[key]#"> 
</cfloop>
```

The above Code give me the below result : 
true 
 3 
[image]

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. [ask] Have you tried anything yet? If so, show us that code and explain how it is not working for you. Some simple searching of the internet or even reading the online documentation will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks to give me such a feedback. <cfset categoryList = application.salesforce.queryObject("SELECT Id, Name FROM Category__c") />
 <cfdump var="#categoryList#">
<cfloop list="#structKeyList(categoryList)#" index="key"> 
<cfdump var="#categoryList[key]#">
</cfloop> I got the results value but not able to iterate on the result value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the additional information. It is too difficult to read in these comments and might also help get rid of the negative votes you are receiving.

Comment: Running your queries through an application scope object could lead to thread safety issues.  You should avoid user the application scope for things like this.

Comment: @DaveFerguson - Depends on whether the components are stateful or stateless. Typically DAO's are stateless. With stateless components, as long you localize all function local variables, then it is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updates that you have made to your question it looks like you might need to do something like this:

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop query="categoryList.results"> 
     <p>#id# - #name# - #type# </p>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

*Note that I have not tested this code*

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty basic question you could have easily found my googling, but here you go anyway.

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop query="queryName">
    #queryName.ID#
    #queryName.name#
    #queryName.type#
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Note you can replace `cfloop` with `cfoutput` and remove the `cfoutput` around everything.

Comment: Thanks For your reply. But i didn't have queryname here. <cfset categoryList = application.salesforce.queryObject("SELECT Id, Name FROM Category__c") /> and the queryObject method return the above struct.

Comment: *Re: i didn't have queryname here* Yes you do. Think about it a minute. The `categoryList` structure contains several keys. One of which represents the query object: `results`. Therefore the query name is `categoryList.results`.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a "cfoutput" tag...

```
<cfoutput query="yourquery">
   #yourquery.ID#
   #yourquery.name#
   #yourquery.type#
</cfoutput>
```